# Where to keep editable config file for Android application?

Tags: android, app-config

I want a config file similar to config.xml in .net so that I can edit that manually from the device. That will have some data which can be modified. One way that I figured out is that keep the file in sdcard in xml form and read that. The question with this approach is whether reading the xml from sdcard in my android app will slow down the performance?

Is there any other way to store the config file that can be changed later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Not sure what the purpose of a config.xml in .net is, but if saving some data that can be modified is what you are looking for, [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) sounds like a good solution.

In case this fits the bill, here are a few tutorials to get you started.

1. http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html
2. http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html
3. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/
4. http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12260/android-sharedpreferences-example/

Comment: I want that an user can edit that file from the device, how can a end-user will edit SharedPreferences?

Comment: @Jai: An end user wouldn't know about such a thing existing in most probability. However, in cases where, say, a login screen is present with a feature that allows the user to remember the password to log in automatically, they would know that something is being stored somewhere. Another example would be Themes in apps that users can switch between and they are stored somewhere.

Comment: @Jai: Now to answer the primary question in your comment. You can inform the user of such a file that will store their _configuration_ (whatever is relevant to your app). You will, however, need to provide them with a UI that will allow them to modify the SharedPref's file. The 1st and 2nd links have examples which allow the users to input data which can then be added / edited / modified / removed from the SharedPref's file. And contrary to the 2nd suggestion, I believe this alternative would be the fastest and the simplest to manage.

Comment: I am looking for something similar myself. It is probably more suited to enterprise/B2B type apps. Config is useful for configuration of logging, network connections etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of entries in your configuration files, you can decide to create a simple database sqlite with a single table, for ex:

```
ID  CONFIG_KEY  CONFIG_VALUE
1      var1          yes
2      var2           30
```

Read/update/add variable to your database. This is more efficient and fast rather than using shared preferences.. but only if you have lots of variable to store.

Imagine every element of your config.xml as a single variable with a value. Easily you can store and retrieve them from a custom database.